# libgdx - AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to create a game using libgdx on Android Studio. When I trigger the "shoot a enemy" command, the error below appeared. 
My bullet class:

```
public void update(float dt)
{
    flipIt();
    stateTime += dt;
    setRegion(fireAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true));
    setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, b2body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
    if((stateTime > 2 || setToDestroy) && !destroyed) {
        world.destroyBody(b2body);
        destroyed = true;
    }
    if(b2body.getLinearVelocity().y > 2f)
        b2body.setLinearVelocity(b2body.getLinearVelocity().x, 2f);
    if((fireRight && b2body.getLinearVelocity().x < 0) || (!fireRight && b2body.getLinearVelocity().x > 0))
        setToDestroy();
}
```

My enemy class:

```
 public void hitOnHead()
{
    setToDestroy = true;
    RPG.manager.get("audio/sounds/coin.wav", Sound.class).play();
    Hud.addScore(330);
}
```

Error log:

> AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed

How can this error be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed" is not an error message, it is a warning telling you that a sound device did not close on exit. It usually happens because a program/game crashes before the sound device got a chance to close.

Comment: how to close on exit sound device in libgdx?